# *ngIf directive with subscribe function

Tags: angular, subscribe

I'm recurrently running into a "problem" working with `*ngIf`. Often the function that returns boolean has a subscribe inside it. As the directive is checked multiple times, multiple requests end up being made and the page crashes. I really don't know how to solve it. Here's an example:

**MyService.service.ts:**

```
myFunction(argument: any): Observable<boolean> {
   // body that returns the observable using HttpClient

}
```

**MyComponent.component.ts:**

```
constructor(private myService: MyService){}

verifySomething(value: number): boolean {

  this.myService.function(value).subscribe((aux) => v); // this is supposed to return what is inside of subscribe to the "upper-function" (verifySomething)
}
```

**MyComponent.component.html:**

```
<tag *ngIf="verifySomething(entity.id)">irrelevant</tag>
```

My first alternative was to do a workaround using a "flag" variable that checks how many times the input occurred...but I don't think it's the best approach.

**Edit: greater detail**

**MyComponent.component.html:**

```
<div *ngIf="values$ | async as values"> 
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let value of values.content">
        <td *ngIf="verifySomething(value.id)"> {{ value.property1 }}
        <td *ngIf="verifySomething(value.id)"> {{ value.property2 }}
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</div>
```

Comment: You can store the value of a subscription in some instances variable and then use that value in ngIf to check your condition.

you can refer to this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-http-service-demo-in-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Example is not exact the same but it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your issue with `async` pipe. Thanks to it, we can work with `async` variables in template.

Firstly, `verifySomething` function has to return observable.

```
verifySomething(value: number): Observable<boolean> {

  return this.myService.function(value);
}
```

Then, we need to update template file. It has to use `async` pipe with `*ngIf` directive.

```
<tag *ngIf="verifySomething(entity.id) | async">irrelevant</tag>
```

Comment: The condition is false even when it was supposed to be true (I've already tested it passing an id hard code). I believe because it is being sent undefined. It would be something with the service method?
`myFunction(argument: any): Observable<boolean> { return this.httpClient.get<boolean>(url...)}`

Comment: No. Your service looks like true. But is the component gets `entity` as an input parameter? You know input parameters are `null` before `ngOnInit`. Can you test it ? I am just brainstorming and I can not reproduce the issue with partial code parts.  @NícolasGeorgeosMantzos

Comment: I added more details. :)
Thanks for the help.